# Basic Syntax Of SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following schema:

[image]

Create a query for the following: Find the age  of  the youngest    participant for each    type    of  activity    that Beginners  participate in.

Wrong solution:

```
SELECT  c.type, MIN(c.age)
FROM    Customers   c
WHERE   c.level = 'Beginner'
GROUP   BY  c.type;
```

Right solution:

```
SELECT  c.type, MIN(c.age)
FROM    Customers   c
WHERE   EXISTS  (   SELECT  *
                FROM    Customers   c2
                WHERE   c2.level = 'Beginner'
                AND c2.type=c.type )
GROUP   BY  c.type;
```

However, I think that the first query would indeed accomplish the desired task because it's guaranteed that there will be at least one beginner in each type because of the c.level=beginner.

Comment: Why do you think there is that "guarantee"?  It's true for the data shown, but it's presumably not always true given the description of the query requested.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  , do you think that we are getting close to solving that problem?. I mean is there any chance someone can invent a piece software which translates the content of an image into latex?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your first query returns the age of the youngest beginner. The question asks for the absolute youngest participant in all categories with at least one beginner.

Therefore, in the second query, when you do the following check:

```
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
               FROM Customers c2
               WHERE c2.level = 'Beginner'
               AND c2.type=c.type )
```

what you are actually doing is to confirm that the category has at least one beginner participant, and then getting the minimum age among all participants in that category.

Comment: it looks like it's an English issue rather than a technical issue. I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this :

```
SELECT      activities.cid,
            activities.slope_id,
            activities.day

FROM        Activities activities
WHERE       activities.cid IN (SELECT   customers.cid
                               FROM     Customers   customers
                               WHERE    customers.level = 'Beginner')
GROUP BY    activities.slope_id,
            activities.cid,
            activities.day
```

You can check this out here -> http://rextester.com/NUZCD25675